# How to undo alias, PATH=$PATH:./Test - (Unix)

Tags: command-line, unix, terminal, alias

**1.)**
In a terminal when we make an alias for any command line,the life of that alias is as long as the terminal is open.

`alias new_command=old_command`

example: `alias dog=cat`

But can we **explicitly** undo the alias command? i.e undo the alias assigned to that command without closing the terminal.

**2.)**
Also when we do something like 
`PATH=$PATH:.:/Test`

We add the files to that directory wherein all the command are stored.How do we undo this?
One way of doing it is by closing the terminal,whats the other way?

I'm new to Unix ,please help.
Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: For general $PATH manipulations see my Stack Overflow question [How do I manipulate $PATH elements in shell scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273909/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) `unalias dog`

2) This will remove the lastmost directory from your path: `PATH=${PATH%:*}`. Repeat it as needed for however many bad entries you've got.

Comment: Carefully with `%`. :)

Answer (score 0):

1) You mean like `unalias` ?